# MongoDB shell aggregation does not work in Morphia

Tags: mongodb, shell, morphia

Consider the following MongoDB collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("..."),
"myId": 12345,
"root": {
    basicData: {
        code: "CODE"
    }
    data: [
        {
            descriptions: {
                description: [
                    {
                        text: "...",
                        language: "de"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}}
```

I'm trying to get documents filtered by "myId" and "code", but with descriptions in only one specific language. In the shell, the following command seems to work properly:

```
db.Items.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { "myId" : 40943 , "root.basicData.code" : "A_CODE"}}, 
  { "$unwind" : "$root.data"}, 
  { "$unwind" : "$root.data.descriptions.description"}, 
  { "$match" : { "root.data.descriptions.description.language" : "de"}}
])
```

In Morphia I try to do the following to get to the same result:

```
AggregationPipeline pipeline = dataStore.createAggregation(Item.class);

Query<Item> matchIdAndCode = dataStore.createQuery(Item.class);
matchIdAndCode.field("myId").equal(myid);
matchIdAndCode.field("root.basicData.code").equal(code);
pipeline.match(matchIdAndCode);

pipeline.unwind("root.data");
pipeline.unwind("root.data.descriptions.description");

Query<Item> matchLanguage = dataStore.createQuery(Item.class);
matchLanguage.field("root.data.descriptions.description.language").equal(language);
pipeline.match(matchLanguage);

Iterator<Item> itemAggregate = pipeline.aggregate(Item.class);
```

but the iterator does not contain any items. I am not shure where to search for further errors, especially because when I copy the stages in the morphia aggregation pipeline to the shell, I get the expected result.

Comment: There is no such field path `root.descriptiveData` in your document. You have the field names wrong.

Comment: Sry, my fault. I corrected my question, fieldnames should be ok, now.

Comment: This code actually works for me with the document you listed.  What are you seeing that makes you think it's not working?

Comment: The iterator (itemAggregate) does not contain any items. It's always empty.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing $ sign in following lines

pipeline.unwind("root.data");

pipeline.unwind("root.data.descriptions.description");

should be

pipeline.unwind("$root.data");

pipeline.unwind("$root.data.descriptions.description");

Comment: this results to a MongoCommandException: "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I now used the MongoDB Java Driver. My working solution:

```
List<DBObject> stages = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
DBCollection collection = dataStore.getCollection(Item.class);

// match
DBObject matchFields = new BasicDBObject("myId", myid);
matchFields.put("code", code);
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields );
stages.add(match);

// unwind
DBObject unwindDescriptiveData = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$root.data");
stages.add(unwindDescriptiveData);
DBObject unwindDescription = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$root.data.descriptions.description");
stages.add(unwindDescription);

// match
DBObject languageMatchFields = new BasicDBObject("root.data.descriptions.description.language", language);
DBObject languageMatch = new BasicDBObject("$match", languageMatchFields );
stages.add(languageMatch);

AggregationOutput aggregate = collection.aggregate(stages);
```

The mapping to the pojo can be done with Morphia again:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (Iterator<DBObject> iterator = aggregate.results().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  items.add(morphia.fromDBObject(Item.class, iterator.next()));
}
```